# golang assemble for memory allocation

Tags: go

```
//  example1.go

packge main

func main() {
    s := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
   _ = s
}
```

s will be allocated in stack and lookup assemble code  not call runtime.makeslice

```
// example2.go
packge main

func main() {
    cap := 1024
    s := make([]byte, 1024, cap)
    _ = s
}
```

s will be allocated in heap and lookup assemble code there is runtime.makeslice   why this ???

```
// example3.go
package main

func main() {
    a := 100
    if a>1 {
        a = 1000
    }
    b := interface{}(a)
    _ = b
}
```

lookup the assemble code and see the compiler is very clever to opt that but in example2.go why don't do this

Comment: Please title your question with the question you wish to ask and explain a little more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is all very dependent on the compiler implementation you're using. You didn't mention the compiler or version, but the standard gc compiler is continuously evolving, and may or may not produce the same output in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the variable nature of your `cap` variable - if you change this to `const cap = 1024` the `runtime.makeslice` call disappears. It seems the Go compiler* is currently unable to infer that `cap` doesn't mutate, i.e. not change in value. As you state; in the last example `a` is evaluated to 1000 at compile time.

** go version go1.7.1 linux/amd64*